# Re-implementation of method which returns primitive type

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, easymock

I need to re-implement a method of a mock with **EasyMock**. The method is defined to return a primitive value.

For re-implementing methods of a mock, EasyMock user guide recommends this way:

```
  expect(l.remove(10)).andAnswer(new IAnswer<String>() {
    public String answer() throws Throwable {
      return getCurrentArguments()[0].toString();
    }
  });
```

This approach is not applicable for me, because I need to use a **primitive return type**.

In the guide, there is another way with `andDelegateTo`. I need to use `andAnswer` approach, not `andDelegateTo`, because:

- I mock a class, not an interface
- when `andDelegateTo` is used, I have to create anonymous class of mocked type, which will call one of its constructors, which is not an option for my case.

Comment: Try using the wrapper type: int -> Integer, boolean -> Boolean, etc.

Comment: `andAnswer` and `andDelegateTo` are equivalent. The later allows a typed solution. And could be useful is you want to spy on a class.

Comment: @Henri andAnswer and andDelegateTo are NOT equivalent in terms of usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640742/easymock-andanswer-vs-anddelegateto Any comments there will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wrapper class of the primitive type, for example:

```java
List listMock = EasyMock.createMock(List.class);

EasyMock.expect(listMock.isEmpty()).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean answer() throws Throwable {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer. All primitive types can be wrapped in `IAnswer`