# EasyMock: andAnswer() vs andDelegateTo()

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, easymock

Which are differences between `andAnswer()` and `andDelegateTo()` methods in EasyMock in terms of usage?

**First difference**

I know that when `andAnswer` method is used, it is skipped the constructor call. This is important if the constructor makes extra things.

```
class Dummy {
    public Dummy(Object someArgument) {
        // some validations of arguments
        System.out.println("the constructor is called");
    }
    public Object method() {
        System.out.println("the method is called");
        return new Object();
    }
}


@Test
public void testSt1() {
    Dummy mock = EasyMock.createMock(Dummy.class);
    EasyMock.expect(mock.method()).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("mocked method is called");
            return new Object();
        }
    } );

    EasyMock.replay(mock);
    mock.method();
}

@Test
public void testSt2() {
    Dummy mock = EasyMock.createMock(Dummy.class);
    EasyMock.expect(mock.method()).andDelegateTo(new Dummy(new Dummy(new Object()) {
        @Override
        public Object method() {
            System.out.println("mocked method is called");
            return new Object();
        }
    } );

    EasyMock.replay(mock);
    mock.method();
}
```

Results:

- `testSt1()` does not call the constructor of `Dummy`
- `testSt2()` calls the constructor of `Dummy`

What are the other differences?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the two methods is to provide different levels of responsibility for your tests. Your example isn't that great, though.

Here's a simple method that demonstrates how functionally these two provide different test expectations.

```
public String foo() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

With `andAnswer`, you can make a mocked version of this method return a String, even though it would never return one in practice. Your use of `andAnswer` implies an expected response.

With `andDelegateTo`, this will always throw an Exception. Your use of `andDelegateTo` implies an actual response.

`andAnswer` means your test-specific code will handle the response. For example, if you create a ParrotAnswer for a MockDao `update` method, the Parrot will return the updated Object, but no Dao is actually instantiated in the process. This is nice for unit testing where you basically walk the test subject through, *but doesn't help if your mocked method doesn't do as what you method actually does.*

`andDelegateTo` allows you to provide an actual Object implementing the interface to handle the response. We're allowing our test subject controlled access to a resource, rather than providing unrestricted access to a full resource. benefit of this is that you can test integration into a test environment, but minimize actual changes to the test environment. For example, you can delegate `get` to a wired Dao to fetch an actual live value from the Db, and mock the `delete` method, so you don't actually delete that same value during testing (and having to recreate it again later to do the same test if it has a static id, for example).